# Save answers using %run file.py

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently running a cluster of files in the loop and checking their answers. Currently, I want to store the variables initialized get when I run a file using `%run file_name.py`

I've attached two examples below, one is the file itself and it's 3 answers.
The second one is the code I am using to compare them.

```
s = 'Amsterdam'
# Print out 'e' using indexing
answer1 = s[2]
print(answer1)

s ='Amsterdam'
# Reverse the string using slicing
answer2 = s[1]
print(answer2)

answer3 = s[::-1]
print(answer3)
```

```
for i in range(1,num_questions+1):
    %run {i}.py
    answers = # HOW DO I MAKE LISTS BASED ON THE NUMBER OF VALUES RETURNED
    if manual == 'N':
        correct_answer_key,question = BitGrading.mannual_answer_key(1)
        print(f'\n The correct answer key for {question} is {correct_answer_key}')
        Grading.grade_question('Q1',student_ids,grade_sheet,answers,correct_answer_key[0])
        print(f'\n{grade_sheet.loc[grade_sheet.ID == student_ids[0]]}')
    else:   
        Grading.grade_question('Q1',student_ids,grade_sheet,answers,correct_answer[0])
        grade_sheet.loc[grade_sheet.ID == student_ids[0]]
```

My main focus is on storing the answers in a list automatically depending on the number of variables returned. The format for answers will always be the same, i.e answer1,answer2,answer3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files only give the answers as output you could use

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['python', '%pathToPYFile%']) # executes the file and saves the output
answers = output.decode('utf-8').split('\r\n')[:-1] # deletes an empty element at the end
print(answers)
```